# Integrability of $\frac{1}{|z|^m}$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

Suppose that we are in $\mathbb C^n$, and consider the unit ball $B_1(0)$ around the origin, I am interested in knowing the integrability of $\frac{1}{|z|^{2m}}$. Specifically, when is
$$\int_{B_1(0)} \frac{1}{|z|^{2m}} \mathrm d\operatorname{vol}< \infty?$$

For $n = 1$, $\int_{B_1(0)} \frac{1}{|z|^{2m}} \mathrm d\operatorname{vol} = \int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{2 \pi} \frac{1}{r^{2m -1}} \mathrm dr \wedge \mathrm d\theta = 2 \pi r^{2-2m} |^{2\pi}_{0}$. So it is integrable only when $m < 1$. What about when $n > 1$?

Comment: "just use the integral is sill 0
 using Fubini" What does that mean?

Comment: I am actually not quite sure about higher dimensions.

Comment: So you're asking about local integrability near $0$, rather than global integrability, I gather.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this context, there's no difference between $\Bbb C^n$ and $\Bbb R^{2n}$. The surface area of a ball of radius $r$ in $\Bbb R^{2n}$ equals $C_{2n} r^{2n-1}$ for some constant $C_{2n}$. Then
$$
\int_{B_1(0)} \frac1{|z|^{2m}}\,dvol = \int_0^1 \frac1{r^{2m}} C_{2n}r^{2n-1}\,dr = C_{2n} \int_0^1 \frac1r r^{2(n-m)}\,dr,
$$
which converges precisely when $m<n$.